# Does ID belongs to view model

Tags: ios, mvvm

After working with MVC for a long time, I decided to go with MVVM. I understood the basics of the pattern and got through multiple articles that explain that MVVM is waaay better then MVC any day. And I am okay with that.

I decided to make my own app in order to set my mind correctly for logic behind MVVM. So I created basic app that does follow MVVM principles and after a while I found the problem that you see in the title.

So, basically, this is the problem. Let's say that I have one object, call it Person. Person have name and surname. But when I want to show details about that person, I will have address, phone numer etc. Because one person can have many phone numbers I will have something from API that link to the user ID.

So we came to my question. If I have some basic information about some model, and want to have detail information about that same model, where do I keep ID (or link) for that detail information? Do I have to keep it inside view controller, which would be just wrong? Or do I keep it inside view model, even if I don't use it really on user interface?

Comment: The ID also belongs to the model class. ie If you have an object `Person` then simply create a data class `Person`, which will obviously include all the members say ID, Name, Address, Number and so on. You can identify each person using the same ID as well.

Comment: Sure thing, Like everywhere, Id will be in model. But question is, does view model needs to know about ID as well?

Comment: Not always required. If you have a list of `Person` objects in view model, then you could easily map each item using the ID. Additionally if you want to have currently selected item or something, you could map it to viewmodel property of that object type ie `Person`. So you need not keep a `PersonID` field in ViewModel unless it is absolutely required for some rare cases.

Comment: Okay sure. First thing that I have to ask you to put it as an answer so I can at least give +1. Second thing is that only sometimes that is needed? So basically in prepareForSegue method I could say something like give me from current VM object at particular index and create VM for new view that I will actually send ? Ofcourse in some cases it is not really possible without ID, but I am talking about simple application. Thanks for your answers :)

Comment: Please don't hide your question underneath blankets of unrelated stuff.

Comment: I don't understand your critic really. I explained background, what could be related to the issue. I could also just write one sentence and say what is in the title which could be misleading really. It's not that long post, every part has about 2 or 3 statements...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID also belongs to the model class. ie If you have an object `Person` then simply create a data `class Person`, which will obviously include all the members say ID, Name, Address, Number and so on. You can identify each person using the same `ID` as well.

The View Model need not always know about the ID. If you have a list of `Person` objects in view model, then you could easily map each item using the `ID`. Additionally if you want to have currently selected item or something, you could map it to viewmodel property of that object type ie Person. So you need not keep a PersonID field in ViewModel unless it is absolutely required for some rare cases.

Sorry, but I did not understand this : `So basically in prepareForSegue method I could say something like give me from current VM object at particular index and create VM for new view that I will actually send ?`

As far as simple applications are concerned, the above approach is more than enough. But in some rare cases, you may need to keep the current selected item's ID in the view model. So if you're using a list and keeping a property for selected item, it may not be the type of that list ie Person. Instead it could be the ID alone.

Hope you got the point.

Comment: Well for that part - I have a list -> select one of the items then I take current view model (which contain that list) and use particular one - the one I selected. It's clear now, thnx